# I have decimal(12,2) type column where I want update value 123456.00 to 12345.6 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a column of type `decimal(12, 2)` and I want update a value 123456.00 to 12345.6 in SQL Server.

My `Weight` column value is 195267.00, and I want to update it to 19526.7.

Comment: Divide the number by 10?

Comment: Yes, you can divide by 10 for an instant: Declare @num decimal(12,2)=195267.0

SELECT @num/10.0

Comment: Thanks Iztoksson

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious things have already been mentioned. If you are very specific about the way it looks, so exactly 12345.6 (don't know why that would matter to you), you might try this:

```
SELECT CAST (CAST (123456.00 AS FLOAT) / 10.0 AS DECIMAL (12,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Update TableName set DecimalColumnName = DecimalColumnName / 10 
//where condition
```

(set where condition if there is any condition to update)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select ROUND(CAST(([weight]/10) AS DECIMAL(12,1)), 2) from yourTable
```